# Bootstrap 4 truncate text display at least two line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a paragraph where I am trying to truncate it by bootstrap class `text-truncate`. In output I am getting only one line.

```
<p class="text-truncate" style="max-width:300px;">
    Resize the browser window to see that its width (max-width) will change at different breakpoints.Resize the browser window to see that its width (max-width) will change at different breakpoints
</p>
```

Getting output

```
Resize the browser window to see that its wid...
```

Expecting output

```
Resize the browser window to see that its width (max-width) 
will change at different breakpoints...
```

In inline css I have tried `-webkit-line-clamp: 2`, getting same result. How can I get multiple line using bootstrap `text-truncate` ?

Comment: Good question. I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

Not built directly into Boostrap4 but here's the  method from [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) -- Bootstrap's code looks like it's built specifically for 1 line. This method, the width needs to be set at the parent element.

```css
.text-truncate-container {
    width: 250px;
}
.text-truncate-container p {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-truncate-container"><p class="text-truncate">Resize the browser window to see that its width (max-width) will change at different breakpoints.Resize the browser window to see that its width (max-width) will change at different breakpoints.</p></div>
```